# Fluent Form Custom Field Ticket Reduction After Form Submit

Tags: wordpress, forms

Using custom Post type called " Courses" and in there is there is custom meta field called "event_tickets" and using fluent form post/CPT selection field to display post titles from custom post type "courses" and other form field attrribute name is "event_tickets" same as custom meta field. Now i want to reduced event ticket once form submitted.

Some how with course post id  form is working for ticket reduction.

But I want as a dynamic course post id can be any.

// Hook into the custom action
add_action('Reduction_Of_Tickets', 'reduce_ticket_count', 10, 1 );

function reduce_ticket_count($form) {

// Hardcode the known course ID
$course_id = 1363;

// Get the current ticket count
$ticket_count = get_post_meta( $course_id, 'event_tickets', true );

// Reduce ticket count by 1
$new_count = max(0, $ticket_count - 1);

// Update the count
update_post_meta( $course_id, 'event_tickets', $new_count );

}